# Which technique is best for updating homescreen app widgets every minute in android?

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, handler, scheduling

I have two types of homescreen app widgets 1. Consisting of text views and 2. Consisting of listview. The first displays data from the arrays and the second one pulls information from the server (i.e. involves networking operations). And they both need to be updated every minute. Now for each case which of the following techniques are best?

```
a) Handler
b) Alarm Manager
c) JobScheduler
d) Firebase JobDispatcher
e) SyncAdapter
f) ..anything else if there is...
```

As a beginner to android it is difficult to decide which technique is the best for the battery life of the devices. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> As a beginner to android it is difficult to decide which technique is the best for the battery life of the devices

The answer is "none of the above — do not attempt to update app widgets once per minute". Google is going to great lengths to prevent you from doing this sort of thing, because users got tired of app developers wasting battery life.

> Handler

`Handler` has little to do with what you are trying to solve. You can use `Handler` and `postDelayed()` to implement an in-process timing loop, but you could also use classic Java solutions like `ScheduledExecutorService`.

However:

- This requires you to have a process running all of the time. As of Android O, this in turn will require you to have a foreground service, meaning that you will have to be showing a `Notification`. Users get irritated by this, as well as by apps that seem to be consuming system RAM continuously for no good reason. And, in practice, you cannot have a process running all of the time anyway, though with a sticky foreground service, you can come close.
- This will not update the app widgets when the device is in Doze mode on Android 6.0+.
- This will not update the app widgets when the device is asleep.

> Alarm Manager

`AlarmManager` would allow you to not necessarily have a running process all of the time. However, this will not update the app widgets when the device is in Doze mode on Android 6.0+.

> `JobScheduler`

`JobScheduler` jobs are inexact (i.e., you do not control exactly when they are run), and I do not know if they can be invoked as frequently as once per minute. Also, this will not update the app widgets when the device is in Doze mode on Android 6.0+, and it will not update the app widgets when the device is in partial Doze mode on Android 7.0+.

> Firebase JobDispatcher

This requires you to have a server, to manage registrations and send high-priority FCM messages every minute. My guess is that Google eventually will prevent servers from doing this.

> SyncAdapter

You have no control over exactly when syncs occur. Also, this will not update the app widgets when the device is in Doze mode on Android 6.0+, and it will not update the app widgets when the device is in partial Doze mode on Android 7.0+.

Comment: I need to show digital clock on home screen widget. So there is a compulsion that it updates every minute. On the second widget i need to update the fresh news. So they need to be updated every minute. In addition i suppose if we do not need to update widget when the screen is off then we do not need to care of Doze mode right?

Comment: @Bishwash: A clock is best implemented as a feature of the home screen, not as an app widget. Updating the news a few times a day, or on user request, would be *far* better than updating the news every minute.

Comment: What change will be in your answer if i asked the same question with updating time every half an hour or every 1 hour ?

Comment: @Bishwash: The techniques, and their limitations, do not change. I am much less worried about doing work at slower frequencies. If your `minSdkVersion` is 21 or higher, I recommend `JobScheduler`. If your `minSdkVersion` is lower than that, either use `AlarmManager` or some wrapper API (e.g., Evernote's `android-job` library) that can hand the work off to the best available underlying engine.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Even I am having the same problem here. What do you mean by implementing the digital clock as a feature of home screen instead of app widget? Could you please provide any references! Thanks!

Comment: @TKB: "What do you mean by implementing the digital clock as a feature of home screen instead of app widget?" -- write a home screen. As part of writing the home screen, add a digital clock as a feature, along with other features that you want to have on in your home screen implementation (e.g., launcher, wallpaper, etc.).\

Comment: @CommonsWare: 1 year passed still stuck on the same issue. I want my notification update every 1 minute without draining significant battery. Please suggest appropriate technologies.

Comment: @Bishwash: There is no means to do anything "every 1 minute without draining significant battery". This is why Android prevents apps from doing this sort of thing.

Comment: @CommonsWare : Then what will be your valuable answer for every 15 minute (or Android allowed duration) ?

Comment: @Bishwash: Do not update a `Notification` based purely on the passage of time. Update the `Notification` only if the information in it needs to be replaced. For doing occasional background work for determining if the information has changed, use `WorkManager` (in 2019+), Firebase Cloud Messaging (if your app is already tied to Play Services and push messaging is a viable approach), `JobScheduler` (on Android 5.0+), or `AlarmManager` (on Android 4.4 and older).